# Inheriting variables from different classes into one class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

How can I inherit variables that exist on different classes?
I need to inherit ticket_id and event_id from ticket and event and check if they are the same on the check class. Next, I need to create an object on the applivation class and the parameters should update themselves every time a value change in event or ticket class.

Class ticket

```
   public class ticket{
    public int ticket_id;
             .
             .
             .
    ticket_id = ...;
    }
```

Class event

```
public class event{
        public int event_id;
                 .
                 .
                 .
        event_id = ...;
       }
```

Class check

```
public class check{

    public check(int ticket_id,int event_id){
    super();
    this.ticket_id = ticket_id;
    this.event_id = event_id;
    }
         .
         .
 getters and setters
         .
         .
         .
```

}

Class Application

```
public class Application{
// the parameters must change everytime they change on the previous classes.
check app = new check(ticket_id,event_id);
             .
             .
             .
}
```

Comment: @1337 Are you serious ?

Comment: @1337 Not even using `extends`?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Not in the way the OP wants it. But yes, I know.. ;)

Comment: @vagg77 The OP wants to inherit from multiple *classes* which is not possible in Java.

Comment: I don't see the need of Inheritance here.. you need the two ids just for the check.constructor, why not just pass two objects (or two ids) in?

Comment: from your question, you already mention `inherit` why not search for `inheritance`

Comment: @1337 :o There's no polymorphism in Java. ?? It is one of the principle features of java. [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Comment: @Mustafasabir Sorry, ment the wrong thing.. yes, I know. I meant multiple inheritance :)

Comment: You can inherit from one class but not from multiple classes. you can implement multiple interfaces

Comment: What if I made 2 constructors with one parameter each?

Comment: then you will be creating two objects as well

Comment: "the parameters should update themselves every time a value change in event or ticket class." -- primitives will be copied after they're sent to the other object's constructor. It seems you're trying to pass a reference to an object instead

Answer (score 0):

The polymorphism in Java only works for methods, **NOT** for variables!

The only thing you could do is to access the variables in the super class if their visibility allows that. Another possible way would be accessing the variables via getters/setters.

Comment: Ι have getters and setters in my check class

Answer (score 0):

A inherit B mean that A is a B, explication : Student would inherit from Person, but not from Date, even if he needs one for the birthday for example, it's not a great example but i hope you understand it. So here, check should not inherit from ticket nor event, but may have to use them so, this is a good way to do it :

```
public class check{

public check(Ticket ticket, Event event){
super();
this.ticket = ticket;
this.event = event;
}
```

and in your application :

```
public class Application{
   Ticket ticket = new Ticket(..);
   Event event   = new Event(..);
   Check check   = new Check(ticket,event);

         .
         .
         .
}
```

or you can directly use the `ticket_id` and the `event_id` without making them attributs of check if you only need them in a method,  :

```
public class check{

public check(){
super();
}

public checking(int ticket_id,int event_id){
      .
      .
      .
}

 public class Application{
   Ticket ticket = new Ticket(..);
   Event event   = new Event(..);
   Check check   = new Check();
   check.checking(ticket.ticket_id,event.event_id);
         .
         .
         .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this is not the right case to use inheritance, apart from your multi-inhert. needs.

If you used Inheritance, usually we can say

> "a subType **is a** superType"

. E.g. "

> a teacher **is a(n)** employee" , "an employee **is a** Person"

and so on.

We don't know exactly your business domain, but you can ask yourself,

> "**is** check a ticket or event"?

I *guess* your answer would be negative.  You may want to say,

> "no, a check **isn't** a ticket or event, a check **has a** ticket and
>   an event".

If it's true, use composition instead of inheritance.

oh, I just realized that there is no codes in my answer... :-)

Answer (score -1):

check should be something like this

```
 public class check{
    public check(ticket t,event e){
    this.ticket_id = t.ticket_id;
    this.event_id = e.event_id;
}
```

i think this should work
tried to implement Kent's suggestion. 
@Kent please feel free to edit if you like